# Is there a word for superstitions which are meant for good?

Tags: word-request

In the Bengali language there are two types of *superstitions*: The good one is called *Sanskar* and the other one is called *Kusanskar*.

Ideally, *Kusanskar* is what we would call [superstition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/superstition?q=superstition) in English, i.e., "excessively credulous belief in and reverence for the supernatural." They come to society automatically out of fear and irrational thinking, in the public mind. They can also be made by some so-called heads of society to gain respect for themselves from the fear in public. For example:

> In early days, Christian priests sold tickets to heaven to the public. The public, out of fear driven by blind faith, bought them and did not question their legitimacy.

The priests created this phobia intentionally, and it had no value in the public interest. This manner of public thought is called *Kusanskar* in Bengali and *superstition* in English.

But some misconceptions were made intentionally to do good for humanity. They are called *Sanskar* in Bengali. They are *blind faith* by society, but at the end of the day they do good for the public. For example, it is a blind faith/custom here in India that:

> A married Hindu girl should wear [Sindur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sindoor).

It may seem to be blind faith, but it had a good intention: to let other people understand whether an Indian girl was married or not. So it should not be taken as bad, rather it has a good intention.

So, what should we call these blind beliefs? Personally, I don't think superstition fits here well. Somehow, it makes any belief stigmatized.

#### Notes

- I am not asking about the cultural situation or examples, but about the words themselves
- Google Translate did not give an alternative

Comment: An ELU question?

Comment: @Novice, What? Why?

Comment: I guess this is not so basic as is expected.

Comment: Novice means this should be asked on (or migrated to) *English Language and Usage*, a site for questions too advanced for ELU. I agree; I don't think such a distinction exists in English but if I'm wrong, these people should be able to help.

Comment: @Novice, I admit I am slowly getting to the state of agreeing you to the point. IF mods think so too, they can migrate it.

Comment: There is *Jinx* which is a superstition with *supposedly* negative consequences, but that's different from what you're asking - avoiding "jinxing it" has no positive or negative bearing on the society, just an alleged influence on your luck.

Comment: The custom of putting a bright red spot on women to signify that that they are taken is "meant for good" compared to some dumb superstition? Don't you realize that it's based on the belief that women are property? So black cats and broken mirrors are bad, but low status of women is good. I don't know whether to laugh or cry.

Comment: What are the consequences if a married woman wants to opt out of that custom? And in what way are married men visibly demarcated?

Comment: @Kaz, Please don't overreact and I definitely can see your point. It's definitely upto a healthy debate which I don't want to enter; please consider understanding the meaning, that was just an example.

Comment: @Kaz, There is no consequence if they part from each other either. "Sindur" is just a symbol of marriage, nothing else. :)

Comment: The meaning is simply that there are beliefs that are connected to supernatural forces. Those beliefs are called superstition (or "religion" when they become very elaborate and organized). People have other beliefs that are not based in fact, and those are not called superstition. Superstititions lead to actions: those actions are simply superstitious rituals. Actions based on certain kinds of non-superstitious beliefs are also rituals or customs.

Comment: @Mistu4u By "opt out of the custom", I mean, she refuses to wear the symbol while remaining married.

Comment: @Kaz, "Opting out of the custom" is a rare scenario, however not unseeable. If the husbands family is open-minded, the wives may decide not to wear "sindur".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the very broad sense, I would regard the first kind ("Kusanskar") as *superstition*, and the second kind ("Sanskar") as *custom* or *[tradition](http://www.wordnik.com/words/tradition)*.

You may want to consider other terms related to *superstition*, too, such as *black magic* or *sorcery*. Also, another word I conjured while reading about the corrupt spiritual lottery you described is *[simony](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/simony)*, which is:

> the buying or selling of sacred or spiritual things, as sacraments or benefices

If you want to stress that these beliefs are untrue, despite how some might believe in them, you could also use the word *[delusion](http://www.wordnik.com/words/delusion)*, which means:

> a false belief or opinion that is resistant to confrontation with actual facts

Comment: +1 But I think the practice OP describes is *indulgences* rather than *simony*.

Comment: _custom_ and _tradition_ cover quite a bit more than 'positively directed superstitions'

Comment: I believe "custom" and "tradition" both fit well for my question.

Comment: -1 kusanskar is not superstition at all..as I am indian and the word is sanskrit. and it means bad manners.

and sanskar means the manners you learn from your parents or family...

correct your answer.

Comment: @Java D Well one Sanskrit word mean different words in different contexts in different regions. The meaning you mean is not what I meant in this question.

Answer (score 12):

To begin with, *superstition* is not a technical term; it is a derogatory characterization employed by one group of people to mock the beliefs and practices of another group of people as irrational or ignorant. For many centuries it was used mainly to express disapproval of another sect’s or people’s religious practices; but today, when a large proportion of people regard *all* religious practices as *superstition*, you find it applied more widely. [Here](http://wac.colostate.edu/books/grammar/chapter6.pdf), for instance, is a book chapter entitled “Grammar Superstitions: The Never-Never Rules”.

So *superstition* doesn't necessarily have anything to do with social value or utility; probably the closest you can come to a true antonym of *superstition* is *rationality*.

Religious people who defend what other people call their *superstitions* have a variety of arguments, and a corresponding variety of terms: *inspired* or *orthodox* or *received wisdom* or *spiritually profound*, and so forth. But practices like the Sindur you describe are not usually, in the West, grounded in religious belief or ritual requirement. They are  *traditions* or *conventions* or *social rituals* or *folkways* or *customs*; and these terms are employed by both those who attack these practices and those who defend them.

There is a large body of literature on the social functionality and dysfunctionality of such practices; but the terms employed there will not, by and large, be part of Standard English. They are, rather, the technical language of sociology, anthropology, rhetoric and semiotics.

Comment: 1 point. Didn't know *superstition* is a derogatory word.

Comment: @Epitorial: But OP himself cited a dictionary definition of *superstition* saying it's *"**excessively** credulous belief"*. I don't see how you could interpret that as anything other than derogatory.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can translate this word into English in any way that would fail to mislead. The corresponding English words - belief, superstition, creed, ritual, tradition, old-wives tale, folkloric practice, etc. all carry a very heavy freight of the history of both religion and rationalism within the society of the English speaking peoples. In no case would it convey what you describe - pair of words deeply embedded in Bengali tradition. I think this is a case where you should simply import the word into English and explain the meaning to the reader.